# ReportViewer Change Control color

Tags: vb.net, colors, controls, reportviewer

I'm looking to change a control's color in my report.RDLC. My reports are all generated by the ReportViewer control on a form called "rv".

The selected rectangle below is the one I'm looking to change colors.
[image: Rectangle3]

It has the following properties:

[image: Rectangle properties]

How do I programmatically change the Background color of the rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a few hours. On the control of which you want to change background colors, select the "Expression" link from the dropdown.

[image: Background color expression]

Afterwards you enter in the code such as:

```
=iif(Fields!State.Value = "Approved", "LightYellow", iif(Fields!State.Value = "Analysis", "LightGreen", "Transparent"))
```

This will set the color of my textbox to light yellow if it's state is "Approved", or light green if it is in it's analysis stage. If none of those are true, it just stays transparent (default).

*Note: My "State" field was added in my dataset so I was able to use it in the expression.